# Trigger dá erro com data

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Eu fiz uma trigger para contar os dias úteis. Ela aceita as datas do mês 06 muito bem, mas outras datas dá o seguinte erro:

```
INSERT INTO `teste` VALUES ("2018-05-01")
#1292 - Incorrect date value: '20180532' for column 'i' at row 1
```

Código da Trigger:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE i date;
    DECLARE j int;

    SET i = DATE(NEW.dataAntiga);
    SET j = 0;

    WHILE (date(i) < NOW()) DO
        if WEEKDAY(date(i)) != 5 AND WEEKDAY(date(i)) != 6 THEN
            SET j = j + 1;
        END IF;
        SET i = date(i)+1;
    END WHILE;
    insert into teste2 values (j);
END
```

Tabela Teste:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tabela teste2:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sua trigger está tentando inserir 32/05/2018 e só

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você fizer isso:

```
SELECT DATE("2018-05-31") + 0;
```

O resultado será esse:

```
20180531
```

Se fizer isso:

```
SELECT DATE("2018-05-31") + 1;
```

Dá isso:

```
20180532
```

Aí é que está o problema. Quando o `i` vai para o dia 31 de maio, você acaba gerando um 32 de maio que não existe. A data é convertida em numeral antes da soma, mas você não quer somar numerais e sim somar datas.

O MySQL tem a função `DATE_ADD` para somar datas. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE("2018-05-31"), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Dá isso:

```
2018-06-01
```

Então, sua trigger deveria ficar assim:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE i date;
    DECLARE j int;

    SET i = DATE(NEW.dataAntiga);
    SET j = 0;

    WHILE (DATE(i) < NOW()) DO
        if WEEKDAY(DATE(i)) != 5 AND WEEKDAY(DATE(i)) != 6 THEN
            SET j = j + 1;
        END IF;
        SET i = DATE_ADD(DATE(i), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
    INSERT INTO teste2 VALUES (j);
END
```

Também acho que se você trocar todos os `DATE(i)` simplesmente por `i`, deve funcionar. Afinal de contas, `i` já é do tipo `DATE`.

Comment: Funciono, muito obrigado !!!